# How to create fling event like android (number picker) in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I want to create my custom number picker in pure javascript for my dashboard, and I want to do the same behavior (fling effect): [demo](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/number/decimal#)

- What events I should use?
- How can get velocity or something similar? [android onFling event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener)
- And others advices that can help me to create my custom number picker

I don't want use external libs.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for inertia/momentum - the basic idea is to calculate some amount of "force" based on the user's initial interaction, use it for your motion, then taper it down over time.

There're several libraries you can use for inspiration for your own implementation if you don't want to just *use* external libraries – this came up googling: https://chrisbateman.github.io/impetus/

Comment: Thank you it is what I need.